# How do I verify entry point for pipeline: Image pull failed, back-off pulling image "hashicorp/terraform:full"

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, terraform, pipeline, terratest

I'm new to containers, pipelines, and images so full noob here. Trying to run Terratest in a Kubernetes container and my go file for Terratest I'm importing the following. I don't think the imports are the problem of the image since the mod and sum file are in the repo already but just in case.

```
    "testing"
    "strconv"
    "github.com/Jeffail/gabs"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform"
    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/azure"
)
```

In my .yml file I have the following:

```
image: golang:latest

include: 
  - template: Terraform/Base.latest.gitlab-ci.yml
...
test:
  stage: test
  image:
    name: "hashicorp/terraform:full"
```

And I keep getting the error:

```
Waiting for pod GitLab-apps/runner-randomstringpart to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod GitLab-apps/runner-randomstringpart to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "": image pull failed: Back-off pulling image "hashicorp/terraform:full"
ERROR: Job failed: prepare environment: waiting for pod running: pulling image "hashicorp/terraform:full": image pull failed: Back-off pulling image "hashicorp/terraform:full".
```

Isn't the template public so I can eliminate that it's a permissions error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such tag `:full` for the image `hashicorp/terraform`. Consider replacing with [an existing tag](https://hub.docker.com/r/hashicorp/terraform/tags?page=1) such as `:latest` or `:1.1.8`.